# Why does transform fail silently?

Tags: r, transform

Say I have a frame with a column of dates:

```
test.frame$alt_dates <- c('2001-01-04', '2001-05-11', '2001-05-14', '2001-07-24', '2003-12-24', '2004-07-21', '2004-10-15', '2004-12-15', '2005-03-17', '2005-07-18')
```

They start out as characters. Okay:

```
class(test.frame$alt_dates)
[1] "character"
```

If I try to use transform to make those dates into dates:

```
transform(test.frame, alt_dates <- as.Date(alt_dates)
```

R just prints my frame to the console. If I transform the column directly it works fine:

```
test.frame$alt_dates <- as.Date(test.frame$alt_dates)
class(test.frame$alt_dates)
[1] "Date"
```

What am I doing wrong with Transform?

UPDATE: As a few folks noticed, I wasn't assigning the results to anything. So that explains the printing to the screen and the not storing any changes. But it doesn't work even if I do capture the results:

```
test.frame <- transform(test.frame, more_dates <- as.Date(more_dates))
class(test.frame$more_dates)
[1] "character"
```

Comment: You need to assign the result of `transform(...)` to an object, i.e. `test.frame <- transform(..., ...)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Andrie and @StephanKolassa say, you need to assign the result.  However, you are making another mistake in your use of `transform` which *happens* to work in this context but will bite you in almost any other case. `<-` and `=` are not interchangeable in this context.  You should use `=` with `transform` (in this case I think it works because the test data frame only has a single column!)

```
test.frame <- data.frame(alt_dates=c('2001-01-04', '2001-05-11', '2001-05-14', 
  '2001-07-24', '2003-12-24', '2004-07-21', '2004-10-15', '2004-12-15', 
  '2005-03-17', '2005-07-18'))
test.frame <- transform(test.frame,alt_dates=as.Date(alt_dates))
```

Comment: Now I'm embarrassed. Yeah ... not assigning the results would explain why the results printed to the console.

Comment: Helpful. there were more columns, so it still didn't work with ->

Answer (score 1):

`transform()` does not fail. R uses [call by value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_by_value#Call_by_value), i.e., arguments to functions are transferred *by value only* - the original object `test.frame$alt.dates` is not transferred. Arguments to functions can therefore not be changed by the function. The alternative, [call by reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_by_reference), would allow a function to modify its parameters in the outer scope. In other programming languages such as C, call by reference is done by passing "pointers" to memory addresses. Not in R.

Simply assign the result of `transform()` to the original object.

Comment: I can [promise](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Promise-objects) you that some folks may nitpick your call by value statement. :) (I agree in spirit, but the details get pretty complicated.)

Comment: Yes, @joran is correct. I believe it's something along the lines of "pass by reference, copy on modify"

Comment: Got it. I was being spacey about assigning the results, but the real issue seems to be that in a dataframe with multiple factors, I need to use `=` in my transform statment, not `<-`