# Function scope - renaming columns

Tags: r

Normally if I was trying to rename the columns of a dataframe in R I'd use

```
data(iris)
colnames(iris)[colnames(iris) == "Petal.Length"] <- "petal_height"
```

So I thought I'd see what happened if I turned this into a simple function

```
renamer <- function(data, oldname, newname) {
  colnames(data)[colnames(data) == oldname] <- newname
}
```

However, while the function runs without errors, it doesn't seem to make any noticeable change to the dataframe.

```
renamer(iris, "Petal.Length", "petal_height")
```

Whereas this just assigns `newname` to the value of iris

```
iris <- renamer(iris, "Petal.Length", "petal_height")
```

Is anyone able to explain why exactly this behaviour is happening?

Please note, I don't actually need a renaming function. I'm just interested in understanding why this doesn't work as I thought it would.

Comment: try to add, `return(data)` at the end of the function

Comment: ...or just `data`

Comment: @missuse Cheers that works fine. Are you able to elaborate on why explicitly calling `return` is necessary? What is the function returning if it is omitted?

Comment: @ConorNeilson https://stackoverflow.com/a/13634526/5414452

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plain:

`renamer(iris, "Petal.Length", "petal_height")`

doesn't change the `iris` object because R uses a local scope inside functions. Changes don't "leak" up to the calling context (without doing special tricks. Don't do that).

When you do:

```
iris <- renamer(iris, "Petal.Length", "petal_height")
```

it doesn't work because the return value from a function is either the argument in a `return(...)` function call or the last thing the function does. So:

```
renamer <- function(data, oldname, newname) {
  colnames(data)[colnames(data) == oldname] <- newname
  return(data)
}
```

Should work with `iris = renamer(iris,....)`

When your function finished with:

```
colnames(data)[colnames(data) == oldname] <- newname
```

then the last thing R did in that function was evaluate `newname`, so it returned `"petal_height"`.

Comment: Under the hood it doesn't copy all the data, because of the clever way R passes things around. The effect is as I described, and you might think it would actually copy all the data, but it doesn't.

Comment: Even a copy with a different name is still only a reference to the same data until the data changes. Not the place to go into details, but you can get addresses of objects with pryr::address if you want to play

Comment: @Renu this isn't the place for extended discussions on R's memory management. Try asking on the R-dev mailing list.

Answer (score -1):

Using `package::dplyr`

```
iris %>% rename_all(function(x)tolower(gsub('\\.', '_', x, perl = TRUE))) %>% colnames()
[1] "sepal_length" "sepal_width"  "petal_length" "petal_width"  "species"
```

#### edit for the comment that this isn't representative of the column names in iris....

```
> data("iris")
> colnames(iris)
[1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"  

> iris %>% rename_all(function(x)sprintf('[OLD]%s | [NEW]%s', x, tolower(gsub('\\.', '_', x, perl = TRUE)))) %>% 
head(1) %>% str

'data.frame':   1 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ [OLD]Sepal.Length | [NEW]sepal_length: num 5.1
 $ [OLD]Sepal.Width | [NEW]sepal_width  : num 3.5
 $ [OLD]Petal.Length | [NEW]petal_length: num 1.4
 $ [OLD]Petal.Width | [NEW]petal_width  : num 0.2
 $ [OLD]Species | [NEW]species          : Factor w/ 3 levels
```

Comment: That doesn't rename the columns in the `iris` data frame.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but as I pointed out, I'm not looking for a way to rename. I'm trying to understand what the function is doing and why it doesn't work

Comment: @Spacedman what? The colnames for iris... are exactly what it renames?

Comment: Do `names(iris)` before and after. Nothing changes. You need to do `iris = iris %>% blah blah()`

Comment: oh... that's because im piping, which doesn't change the initial dataset ... see what you did there.